# Shortcut keys in ScreenTips Word 2016 not shown even when checked

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

In Word 2016 you should see shortcut keys in ScreenTips, when you have the option turned on. Like this:
[image: Word advanced settings]

Even though I have this option turned on, I never see the shortcuts. See here:
[image]

What's the problem here?

Comment: Leave it to office to have a setting that doesn't work even when turned on.

Comment: http://goo.gl/4Q8kxz posted the question to answers.microsoft. Hoping for some attention.

Comment: Same problem still in the latest Word for Office 365 version 16.0.11929.20298 32-bit as of 20190920. No response from answers.microsoft.com.